# Magical Record - context (not saving)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, magicalrecord

I'm completely unsure what's the problem. I'm creating a new object and inserting it into context:

```
Object *object = [Object MR_createEntity];
object.name = @"blahblah";
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Saving.md) I shouldn't use `+ MR_contextForCurrentThread` so I don't:

> In particular, do not use +MR_contextForCurrentThread from within any of the +[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:…] methods — the returned context may not be correct!

However if I open my app data I can see 3 files (1)`appname.sqlite`, (2)`appname.sqlite-shm` and (3)`appname.sqlite-wal`. As far as I know 2&3 are only cache. When I open file 1 accompanied by 2 and 3 I can see all my data. However when I open only file 1 (copied somewhere far from 2&3) there is no data in my database, so I suppouse something isn't working ok.

The problem is visible only on the device not on the simulator and only if you copy .sqlite to your computer from app data. If you copy all 3 files you can see all the records, but it suggest that everything is saved in cache instead of sqlite.

Maybe I should exchange `[Object MR_createEntity]` to `[Object MR_createInContext:context]` because the object is created but not inserted into persistent store?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've given here is correct. The shm file is called the Shared Memeory log. And wal is called the Write Ahead Log. They are there to help SQLite perform saves and fetches faster. That said, you should always be able to open up the sqlite file and see whats in the data store.

With that, some things to look at are to enable the logs. Likely your data is not saving because you have specified a property as required and did not fill it in. Also, you may be looking in the wrong place o

Comment: Well in this case I wouldn't see this data also in wal and shm file, but when I attach these 2 files I can see all the data. After opening with external editor these files get merged with .sqlite and from then I can see everything using only .sqlite without wal and shm files.

Comment: Then the best way to put all your data into a single sqlite file (like it was before) is to have a look at the pragma options for sqlite and set the appropriate one prior to setting up your store. SQLite didn't seem to respond to updates to the pragma settings once the store is created, but I may have been doing things wrong there...